# Where to find the meaning of the seasonal 'hats'

Tags: support

I strangely got a hat and tried to find out its 'meaning', profile only says "it is a secret hat". Nonetheless, I carefully adjusted it to my 'head' and think it looks pleasing.

(Nevermind the irony of butterfly wearing a Menorah. Behold, the Iron Butterfly. *"Inna gadda da vita, honey, don't cha know that I love you?"*)

Comment: [Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/139866) -- the "Row Of Many Candles" was awarded for any participating in a site during the last day of Hanukkah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How fortunate that you dream of being a butterfly [1] and not a moth [2].

There are usually topics on the main meta site, discussing the year's "secret hats" [3].

If there's no answer yet, there'll probably be an answer there at the end of this Winter Bash.

It does look good on ya, adroitly placed. It reminds me of a lotus there, as it floats above.

[1] - https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Zhuangzi
[2] - https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/232050.html
[3] - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secret-hats?sort=newest

Comment: Thank you! *"I have dreamed a dream... But now that dream has gone from me."*